# Responsive Image Adds Spacing

Tags: image, html, css

For some odd reason I added a responsive image to my responsive layout and it seems to add some sort of spacing below the image.

You may view the issue here: http://www.client.noxinnovations.com/jensenblair/

The top image. Here is my HTML and CSS.

HTML

```
<div class="header"> <img src="images/photograph.jpg" /> </div>
```

CSS

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}
.header {
    height: auto;   
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: none;
}
```

It seems to be consistent in each browser. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Try `display:block;` for `img`

Comment: Thank you Shmiddty. I should of known that. Make this an answer and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways (that I know of) to solve this: http://jsfiddle.net/3kC4K/1/

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/"/>
</div>

<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/" class="block"/>
</div>

<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/" class="inline"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    border:solid 1px #f00;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
}

.block{
    display:block; 
}

.inline{
    vertical-align:bottom;
}​
```

`img` tags, by default, are `inline` elements. Because of this, browsers will create a sort of "gutter" underneath them so that any text that wraps below it won't be flush with the bottom of the image.

In your case, simply applying `display:block` to the image should do the trick.

Comment: +1 for `vertical-align: bottom;` (or `vertical-align: top;`), which won't modify the surrounding layout flow (like `display: block;` or `float: xxx;` will).

Comment: Thank you so much Schmiddty! I believe that display: block is the better choice, but it's good to know of multiple ways to fix something! Thank you again!